# The solution of linear air drag and transcendental number $e$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

I was watching a course about classical mechanics and in the chapter on air resistance  the instructor wanted to show how transcendental numbers  appear to the solution of linear air drag differential equation (he ignored the quadratic drag for the time being ) \begin{gather} m\dot{v}=-bv \end{gather}which can be rewritten into \begin{gather} \dot{v}=-\frac{b}{m}v. \end{gather}

Then he said that: because the acceleration is just some factor of the velocity then every time we increase the velocity by the factor of $-b/m$ and then he illustrated that if the the particle began with intial velocity $v_{0}$  then the velocity after one second will be $v_{0}(1-\frac{b}{m})$ and after $n$ seconds the velocity will be $v_{0}(1-\frac{b}{mn})^{nt} $ such that $n$ is how much we divide the time and it's integer number

My question is: how could he suppose that? we can't just say that the velocity at any time is just gets increased by some factor we should integrate our acceleration from $t=0$ to some $t$ to get the velocity \begin{gather}  \int_{0}^{t}a dt=v(t)-v_{0} \end{gather}

Comment: $e$ shows up in a LOT of linear physics.

Answer (score 1):

Your last equation, with the notation slightly tweaked for clarity, is
$$
\int_{0}^{t}a(t') dt'=v(t)-v_{0}.
$$
This is correct, strictly speaking — it's essentially just a statement of the fundamental theorem of calculus.  But it's not terribly helpful unless you know what $a(t)$ is.  And since $a(t) = - b v(t)/m$ in this case, this means that your equation amounts to
$$
- \frac{b}{m} \int_0^t v(t') \, dt' = v(t) - v(0).
$$
This is not terribly useful for finding the unknown function $v(t)$, since it appears both inside and outside the integral.

To show that the video's method is correct, let's imagine dividing up the time interval $[0,t]$ into $N$ equal intervals, with the $i$th interval spanning $[(i-1)t/N, it/N]$.  Now, for "small" intervals $\Delta t$, we have
$$
\Delta v \approx \frac{dv}{dt} \Delta t, 
$$
where the approximation becomes exact in the limit $\Delta t \to 0$. In particular, this means that over the $i$th time interval we have
$$
v_{i+1} - v_i \approx - \frac{b v_i}{m} \Delta t
$$
where $v_i \equiv v(it/N)$. Rearranging, this means that
$$
v_{i+1} \approx \left( 1 - \frac{b t}{m N} \right) v_i.
$$
(This seems to be the point you were unsure about in the video. Note that it relies on the idea that $dv/dt$ is proportional to $v$;  if, for example, we had $dv/dt \propto v^2$ or $dv/dt =$ const. this method wouldn't work.)

From here, this implies that
$$
v(t) = v_N \approx \left( 1 - \frac{b t}{m N} \right)^N v_0
$$
Of course, this is only approximate because we're looking at a series of $N$ finite time intervals.  But if we take the limit as $N \to \infty$, then the approximation I made in the first step approaches exactitude, and so we have
$$
v(t) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{b t}{m N} \right)^N v_0 = v_0 e^{-bt/m}.
$$

Comment: but we know that the solution of this differential equation is $v(t)=v_{0}e^{\frac{-t}{\tau }}$ , but he concluded the same solution by taking the limit of n goes to infinity of the equation he proposed , My question is how his proposition is even correct ? he just said the velocity gets increased by factor without even integrating

Comment: The instructor is just trying to solve the differential equation without calculus for the weaker students. If you know how to integrate, just do it, and avoid the weird stuff we have to do when we lack calculus.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent , how his approach is even correct?

Comment: It is wrong, but good enough to have to correct limiting behaviour. Again, if you already have the calculus skills to get the answer directly, there is no need to go for his trickery

Comment: @amin:  If that's what you're trying to ask then please update your question to reflect it.  It's not at all clear that that's what you're asking about, which is why my answer here didn't address it.

Answer (score 1):

the solution of this $~\dot v=-\frac bm\,v~$ ODE with the initial condition $~v(0)=v_0~$  is:

$$v(t)=v_0\,e^{-\frac bm\,t}=\lim_{n\mapsto\infty}v_0\,\left(1-\frac {b}{m\,n}\right)^{n\,t}$$

where n is integer number

with $~n\,t=\tau_i~$

$$v_i=v_0\,\left(1-\frac {b}{m\,n}\right)^{\tau_i}$$

you obtain

$$v_1=v_0\,\left(1-\frac bm\right)\quad,n=1,t=1\\
v_2=v_0\,\left(1-\frac 12\frac bm\right)^2\quad n=2,t=2\\
v_3=v_0\,\left(1-\frac 13\frac bm\right)^3\quad n=3,t=3\\
\vdots\\
v_k=v_0\,\left(1-\frac 1k\frac bm\right)^k\quad n=k,t=k$$

thus the
$$v_i=v_{i-1}+c_i\quad,i=1\ldots\infty\quad,c_0=0$$

where $~c_i~$ are constant

> we can't just say that the velocity at any time is just gets increased by some factor

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a good idea which gets bogged down when looked at in any detail.

For simplicity assume that the equation is $\dfrac {dv}{dt} = - k v$ and then make the approximation $\dfrac {\delta v}{\delta t} \approx - k v \Rightarrow \dfrac {\delta v}{v} \approx - k\, \delta t $.

This final form says that the fraction change in the velocity in a time $\delta t$ is **approximately** equal to $- k\, \delta t $ which constant if $k$ and the time interval $\delta t$ are constant.

Suppose that you are given the velocity $v(0)$ and are asked to find the velocity after some time $T$.
As a first approximation one could say that in a time $T$ the velocity has decreased by k ,T ,v(0)  and so the velocity at time $T$ is given by $v(T) = v(0)-k \,T \,v(0) = (1-k\,T)v(0)$.
A better approximation is to split the time interval $T$ into two equal parts such that $\delta t = T/2$.
So in the first interval of time the velocity had decreased by $k \,\frac T 2 \,v(0) \Rightarrow v(\frac T2) = (1-k\,\frac T2)v(0)$.
In the second interval of time the velocity had decreased by $k \,\frac T 2 \,v(\frac T2) \Rightarrow v(T) = (1-k\,\frac T2)v(\frac T2)$.

Thus $v(T)= (1-k\,\frac T2) \times (1-k\,\frac T2)\, v(0) =  (1-k\,\frac T2)^2\,v(0)$.

In general cutting the time interval into $n$ equal part each of length $\frac Tn$ results in a final velocity $v(T) = (1-k\,\frac Tn)^n\,v(0)$

Now why is this a better approximation?

If $k=1$ and $v(0) =1$ what is the velocity after $0.5$ units of time, ie when $T=0.5$.

[image]

The approximation predicts that the velocity after $0.5$ units of time is $0.5$ whereas the actual value (black curve) is $0.606$.

Now split the time interval of $0.5$ units of time into two intervals each of length $0.25$.

[image]

Now the blue and red segments are a better approximation to the accurate graph and the final velocity $0.56$ is closer to $0.606$.

Instead of drawing graphs one can cut up the time interval $T=0.5$ into $n$ parts each of length $\frac Tn$ and evaluate $v(T) = (1-k\,\frac Tn)^n\,v(0) = (1-\frac {0.5}{n})^n$ for our numerical example using a [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281-0.5%2Fn%29%5En%2C+n%3D1000).

$n=1 \Rightarrow v(0.5) = 0.5 . . .$

$n=10 \Rightarrow v(0.5) = 0.599 . . .$

$n=100 \Rightarrow v(0.5) = 0.6057 . . .$

$n=1000 \Rightarrow v(0.5) = 0.60645 . . .$

$n=10,000 \Rightarrow v(0.5) = 0.606523 . . .$

etc

To be compared with $e^{0.5} = 606531 . . .$

Convergence not so good but on the other hand it shows how good the Calculus is.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answers:
It is simply a particular case of using a numerical resolution of a differential equation by Euler's method. Some simple examples of this type of resolution was already shown by Feynman in his famous course. See this link :
[Feynman : chapter 09](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_09.html)

The particularity of this example is that the author is not satisfied with a numerical result. It passes to the limit of the process and finds the exact analytical solution.

Regarding the rigor of this type of proof : it is this kind of method that is used to mathematically prove the existence and the uniqueness of the solution of a first order differential equation with an initial condition. See this link :
[Picard's iterative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.